# on clicking the picture it should get stored in the internal storage of my mobile

Tags: java, android, json

I am newbie in creating android app.The problem is i am only able to open my camera after clicking the camera button but when i click the picture it does not get stored in my mobile anywhere.So i want that when i open my camera through the camera button i should be able to click a picture and able to store it in my mobile somewhere in an directory in the internal sorage of my mobile such as ("pitchers directory under some other folder name as (camera demo folder)")

my java file is-

```
public class B1ITEM1L3 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_b1_item1_l3 );

    JSONArray jsonArray=getJSonData( "B1ITEM1DATA.json" );

    ArrayList<JSONObject> listItems=getArrayListFromJSONArray(jsonArray);

    ListView listV= findViewById(R.id.list_viewL3ITEM1);

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListadapterB1ITEM1 (this,R.layout.list_layoutb1item1,R.id.textView,listItems);

    listV.setAdapter(adapter);

}
private JSONArray getJSonData(String fileName){

    JSONArray jsonArray=null;

    try {

        InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open(fileName);

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] data = new byte[size];

        is.read(data);

        is.close();

        String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");

        jsonArray=new JSONArray(json);

    }catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (JSONException je){

        je.printStackTrace();

    }

    return jsonArray;

}

private ArrayList<JSONObject> getArrayListFromJSONArray(JSONArray jsonArray){

    ArrayList<JSONObject> aList= new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        if (jsonArray != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                aList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));

            }

        }

    }catch (JSONException je){je.printStackTrace();}

    return  aList;
}

public void opencamera(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    startActivity( intent );
} }
```

my listadapter file is-

```
class ListadapterB1ITEM1 extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

int vg;

ArrayList<JSONObject> list;

Context context;

public ListadapterB1ITEM1(Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<JSONObject> list){

    super(context,vg, id,list);

    this.context=context;

    this.vg=vg;

    this.list=list;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(vg, parent, false);

    TextView txtId= itemView.findViewById( R.id.textView);

//    TextView txtName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //   TextView txtSex=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsex);

    try {

        txtId.setText(list.get(position).getString("id"));

  //      txtName.setText(list.get(position).getString("name"));

        //     txtSex.setText(list.get(position).getString("sex"));



    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }



    return itemView;

}
```

}

main xml file is-

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_viewL3ITEM1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="453dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="save as draft"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_viewL3ITEM1"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="cancel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_viewL3ITEM1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

list layout xml file is-

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="29sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="228dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.978"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:onClick="opencamera"
    android:layout_width="78dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="345dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage"
    android:hint="Leave a Comment"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First open the camera Intent on button click

```
   if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            } else {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } 
        }
```

In this method you will get your capture bitmap

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        storeImage(photo);

    }  
}
```

Mehtod for storing bitmap as png in your internal storage

```
 private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
if (pictureFile == null) {
    Log.d(TAG,
            "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
    return;
} 
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
}  
 }
```

Comment: Faiz ,i know this set of code but it is not working in my java file

Comment: but in your Activity you don't have any onActivityForResult method

Comment: ?? in which one and meaning what

Comment: B1ITEM1L3  in this class your opening intent for camera..but you are not accepting data from this intent

Comment: so where and what code should i implement in my present java files to make the above for storing the pic

Comment: I provide all the snippet above for accepting image from Intent and store it

Comment: yes Faiz ,thanks i have seen the code and i myself have also tried writing the code in my java file but cannot as it shows an error could you help me out to tell where show i put this particular code to run the program

Comment: ok Faiz i contact you through mail in some hours and i can slowly understand what ever you'll tell me to learn my mistake much better.